# Infinite progressbar with js toastr

Tags: javascript, toastr

Is it possible to make a toastr notification with ProgressBar that last forever or until I disable it manually in code?

I want to show it on ajax data saving and I don't know how much time will it take.

Comment: I see my previous answer was already deleted despite the not-cool and wrong answer above. as TFerrel already stated in other thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403632/how-to-assign-id-to-toastr-js-notification-and-update-it-as-needed/30658165?noredirect=1#comment59633968_30658165
"There is currently no way to show indeterminate progress."

Comment: OK, I get your problem.

I am answring in 2 place

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You should use web-workers HTML5 API for doing this with the toaster plugin.

An example of using toaster plugin for ever is given [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403632/how-to-assign-id-to-toastr-js-notification-and-update-it-as-needed/36004999#36004999).

---

A **demo** web-workers HTML5 API demo is here:

```js
var w;

function startWorker() {
    if(typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
        if(typeof(w) == "undefined") {
            w = new Worker("demo_workers.js");
        }
        w.onmessage = function(event) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data;
        };
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Workers...";
    }
}

function stopWorker() { 
    w.terminate();
    w = undefined;
}
```

```html
<p>Count numbers: <output id="result"></output></p>
<button onclick="startWorker()">Start Worker</button> 
<button onclick="stopWorker()">Stop Worker</button>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions do not support Web Workers.</p>
```

You should define your work in the `startWorker()` function.

You can use **AJAX** for updating data also :) like this-

```
$.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
    $("#div1").html(result);
}});
```

For updating data from server.

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use fake time to indicate progress; as all we know an ajax request may take approx. 30sec;

We can create a function  to show fake progress bar for 30 sec.;

If we get response before 30 sec. we set progress to 100% whatever it's now and will show response to user;

Else if request doesn't complete in 30 sec.; we can set progress to 99% and wait for response from server and when we get response we'll set it to 100% and will show response to user; :)